# How can i use dictionary comprehensions where nested dict or list may occur

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I use dictionary comprehension for values that are `literals` or `list`

Right now I'm able to iterate through a nested dictionary and get as a result dict with nested values, but I would like to include in the output `dict`, list, and literals (int, str)

Here is my example ( I know that `isinstance` is not needed here)

```
nested_dict = {'first':{'a':1}, 'second':{'b':2}, 'third': 3, 'fourth': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

float_dict = {
    outer_k: { float(inner_v)
        for (inner_k, inner_v) in outer_v.items()}
            for (outer_k, outer_v) in nested_dict.items()
                if isinstance(outer_v, dict) 
}

print(float_dict)
```

Expected output:

```
{'first': {'a': 1.0}, 'second': {'b': 2.0}, 'third': 3.0, 'fourth': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: same dictionary but only each value converted to floating point

Comment: You mean that the `third` and `fourth` key also become floats?

Comment: yes, exaclty...

Comment: If the input isn't uniform, you can't really do it (reasonably) with a single comprehension. You'll want a recursive function which specifically checks whether it's dealing with lists, dicts or single values and treats them accordingly (recursively). E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55704719/476

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not (reasonably) possible using a single comprehension, you want a recursive function like this:

```
def floatify(v):
    if isinstance(v, list):
        return list(map(floatify, v))
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        return {k: floatify(_v) for k, _v in v.items()}
    return float(v)
```

```
>>> floatify(nested_dict)
{'first': {'a': 1.0}, 'second': {'b': 2.0}, 'third': 3.0, 'fourth': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}
```

---

Note that you can make this function even more generic:

```
def anyify(v, f):
    if isinstance(v, list):
        return [anyify(_v, f) for _v in v]
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        return {k: anyify(_v, f) for k, _v in v.items()}
    return f(v)

anyify(nested_dict, float)
```

Comment: @deceze Really nice. Thank you! 
One more question for a kind of similar task, if I need to process key instead of value, for example, i need to lowercase all dict keys in case they are uppercased, now most probably I will not be able to access nested dict if `key` will be lowered

Comment: @Andrew Basically the same thing, but you'd process the `k` in the dict comprehension. I'm sure you can figure it out with a bit of work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237139/discussion-on-answer-by-deceze-how-can-i-use-dictionary-comprehensions-where-nes).

Answer (score 2):

Or without recursion you could kinda make it in one-liner:

```
{outer_k: ({inner_k: float(inner_v) for (inner_k, inner_v) in outer_v.items()} if isinstance(outer_v, dict) else ([float(i) for i in outer_v] if isinstance(outer_v, list) else float(outer_v))) for (outer_k, outer_v) in nested_dict.items()}
```

Ex:

```
nested_dict = {'first':{'a':1}, 'second':{'b':2}, 'third': 3, 'fourth': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

float_dict = {outer_k: ({inner_k: float(inner_v) for (inner_k, inner_v) in outer_v.items()} if isinstance(outer_v, dict) else ([float(i) for i in outer_v] if isinstance(outer_v, list) else float(outer_v))) for (outer_k, outer_v) in nested_dict.items()}
print(float_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'first': {'a': 1.0}, 'second': {'b': 2.0}, 'third': 3.0, 'fourth': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}
```

Comment: 1) This is horrible.  2) It doesn't work for arbitrarily nested data structures…

Comment: @deceze Yeah, but for this scenario of the OP's dictionary it works :P

Comment: Call me old fashioned, but I prefer [readable and generically applicable solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69191414/476)…

Comment: @deceze True, but it is horrible in an impressive sort of way and makes a good motivation for your answer. +1 to both.

Comment: @deceze Me too :P I was ready to provide a solution with recursion as well, but since you already did, thought to do this crazy dictionary comprehension

Comment: @deceze I guess this is close to the limit of how ugly python syntax can become haha :)

Comment: Do not tempt the daemons… ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @deceze Haha! Exactly!

Comment: It's not _quite_ as ugly with a few well-placed linebreaks and shorter names for `k/v`, though...

Comment: @tobias_k Yah, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses a queue. By taking advantage of the mutability of dicts and lists, we can enqueue those objects (even inner ones and even how deeply nested) and still be able to update the source data. This will traverse and enqueue each inner element of the data. If the element is an int, it will convert it to float.

```
import copy

nested_dict = {'first':{'a':1}, 'second':{'b':2}, 'third': 3, 'fourth': [4, {"fifth": 5}, 6, [{"sixth": [7, 8]}, 9], 10]}

float_dict = copy.deepcopy(nested_dict)

queue = [float_dict]
while queue:
    data = queue.pop()
    items = data.items() if isinstance(data, dict) else enumerate(data)
    for key, value in items:
        if isinstance(value, int):
            data[key] = float(value)
        elif isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
            queue.append(value)

print(float_dict)
```

Output

```
{'first': {'a': 1.0}, 'second': {'b': 2.0}, 'third': 3.0, 'fourth': [4.0, {'fifth': 5.0}, 6.0, [{'sixth': [7.0, 8.0]}, 9.0], 10.0]}
```

Comment: This is exactly *not* recursive. You've unrolled the recursion into a loop. Which may be beneficial for very very *very* deeply nested data structures…